# Create my own classList object when the browser does not implement it itself

Tags: javascript, dom

I have JavaScript code that adds and removes classes using the `classList` object.
The code is up and working correctly as expected until I received complaints about it because it does not work in Opera and in IE8.

I don't want to use any frameworks or code libraries. I'd like to reduce to a max the code I have to change in my program so I wanted to make my own `classList` object and add it to the node object. I already have this code:

```
if (typeof(document.createElement('input').classList) == 'undefined') {
    HTMLElement.prototype.classList = new function () {
        this.add = function (addClass) {
            this.className += addClass;
        }
    }
}
```

which, obviously, does not work.
The problem is: I can't access the `HTMLElement.className` of this object like this. How can I accomplish that? How can I make this object to work similar to or exactly like the original?

Comment: The MDC has listed a classList shim here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList There's quite a bit going on in the code, but looks to be what you are after.

Comment: Please add that as an answer, not just as a coment. It was the best yet.

Comment: No problem, it's now an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mozilla has listed a classList shim here:

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList

There's quite a bit going on in the code, but looks to be what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending the prototype you can just create a helper function that returns the values you need:

```
classList = function ( elem ) {
    return elem.className.replace(/\s+/g,' ').split(' ');
};
```

Then instead of calling `elem.classList` you'd just call `classList(elem)`, meaning it doesn't work exactly like the original but it returns the same data.

Comment: But for that I have to replace that in all the code! And that way it won't use the native code where it is available. That is no solution to my problem.